# invalid tokens in android XML

Tags: android, xml

Just starting android development and trying to create a UI here.. but getting the following: /res/layout/main.xml:13: error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >
  <TableLayout android:id="@+id/entryBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    >
    <TableRow
      <EditText android:id="@+id/taskEntry" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
      <Button android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
      />
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
  <ListView android:id="@+id/tasks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/entryBar"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a > after the first <TableRow

Answer (score 2):

Your `TableRow` items aren't ended correctly, try...

```
<TableRow>
  <EditText android:id="@+id/taskEntry" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
  <Button android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
  />
</TableRow>
```